# Background event on Highcharts Gantt

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

Here is for a project we used before FullCalendar in resourceView mode to display a from an algorithm. In this gantt we have jobs, as well as the display of the unavailability of resources (workstation here).

**Sandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-microservice-fuv76?file=/src/GanttMain.jsx

Here is a screenshot of the old Gantt with Fullcalendar :
[image]

We changed for Highcharts for the reactivity and especially the reordering which will be simpler with Highcharts, only I do not know if it is possible, and if yes how, to display events in "background" mode which passes under the jobs. Would you have a solution for me ?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code and some sample data - see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Yes sorry, i updated my post

Comment: Hi @Minos, What do you exactly mean by `display events in "background" mode which passes under the jobs`?

Comment: @ppotaczek Sorry, maybe my translation is a bit bad. I'm just trying to create events of my unavailability displayed behind the job events, as if there was a zindex of differences, as on the first screenshot, the grey slots are background events

Answer (score 0):

You need to use plot bands for x-axis:

```
xAxis: {
  ...,
  plotBands: [
    {
      from: 1613361600000,
      to: 1612841640000,
      color: "gray"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-moon-nx4y-nx4y8?file=/src/GanttMain.jsx

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.plotBands

Comment: Yes I have seen this api, but the problem is that the plot bands fill the whole height of the gantt. I need something that can be adapted to each resource, because they are all independent. 
Sometimes you can have an unavailability on a whole cell but not the others, and sometimes an unavailability on a workstation for a few hours.

Comment: Hi @Minos, In this case you need to use polygon series: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-moon-nx-vfjs4?file=/src/GanttMain.jsx or render custom shapres by `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: Ok I will look at the polygons series thank you very much. I was also told about the SVGRenderer, I have another project in progress, I cannot yet test well but this solution seems correct to me if I manage to convert the axes to hours to define a width, and the position to Y ... I'll test!